# Identity Server Flows. Whats the right one?

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a web and mobile application that communicate with multiple services. I am thinking of using Identity server 4 for Authentication and Authorization but I am stuck at selecting the right flow for mobile application. After reading and watching few videos I thought Hybrid is more secure and better but it doesn't make sense to use Hybrid flow for mobile users considering they are our application users and we are not using any external providers.

It seems not very user friendly to go through OpenId Interactive flow with our application users.

So I am not sure what could be right, secure and long lived token flow that would suit for mobile flows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hybrid flow with PKCE is best practice for mobile applications. This gives you the most secure user and client authentication that you can with a public client running on a mobile device.

Authorization Code is also acceptable, but with Hybrid you get an identity token that you can verify straight away before exposing secrets or verification codes.

See [RFC 8252 - OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) for best practices and in-depth explanation.

Comment: Are big companies like Google use hybrid flow to log in their own users. As hybrid feels not user friendly

Comment: Yes, they are. They help write these specs too. Google especially. In-app browser tabs are used by most major companies. The alternative is not secure: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

Comment: What @ScottBrady said.
Mobile platforms also offer up other opportunities to improve UX - for example using secure enclave to protect a refresh token which means you don't have to prompt for credentials interactively so often.

Comment: @mackie Can you please provide link to an example.

Comment: I don't have an example of what I mentioned above, it was more a general comment that modern mobile platforms offer features that allow you to improve UX without sacrificing security.